# Reading different variables in while loop in PHP

Tags: php, variables, while-loop

I'm a Flash (AS2) programmer trying to do the following in PHP:

```
while (var i=1;i<6;i++){
   echo descriptionTextForDay[i]
}
```

where `descriptionTextForDay1` - `descriptionTextForDay5` are previously defined strings, *not* members of an array.

The code above is how I'd have done it in AS2 (except for the `echo`), but how would you do this in PHP?

Sorry if it's a basic question, but I've passed my eyes through the documentation without finding any answers.

Comment: Please [review the language reference section](http://php.net/langref).  *Please*.

Comment: I did - I think you're missing what I'm asking about. I know that you'd use a "for" loop etc. and I know you'd need semicolons in php, that you don't use "var" and so on - but I couldn't find anything on how [] is used (outside of arrays) in php. (which is the only thing I actually needed help with)

Comment: You might want to go back and read it again.  You'd have come across [variable variables](http://php.net/language.variables.variable), which are actually closer to what AS2 does than using an array instead.  They're also a *horrible* idea and shouldn't be used unless you have no other choice.  I suppose, then, that it all worked out for the best!

Comment: Well, obviously the answer is in there, and obviously I missed it - I'm not saying the documentation is incomplete. But, it was way faster for me to ask about this one particular thing rather then going through the entire reference with a magnifying glass looking for something I didn't even know the terminology for. (thanks for letting me know they're called "variable variables")

Comment: And now, you'll never forget!  Just make sure to never use them until you hate...er.. understand their downfalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use a `for` loop, like this:

```
for( $i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    echo $descriptionTextForDay[$i];
}
```

Also:

1. Variables start with a dollar sign.
2. The `var` keyword is not recommended for use (and not used in this context).
3. Statements end with a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Use foreach!

```
foreach($descriptionTextForDay as $index => $content) {
  echo "$index is $content";
}
```

$index is optional, you may also do:

```
foreach($descriptionTextForDay as $content) {
  echo $content;
}
```

The former is more useful if you declare an array that has useful keys, like:

```
$myArray = array(
 'timmy' => 'bad',
 'jimmy' => 'good',
);

foreach($myArray as $boy => $status) {
  echo "$boy is $status\n";
}

// Output:
// timmy is bad
// jimmy is good
```

Good luck transitioning!

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
$i = 0;
 while($i<6){
   echo $descriptionTextForDay[$i];
   $i++;
  }
```